# Plot with two-digit noation in scatter plot

Tags: r, plot

The code  `plot(1,1, pch = "13")` plots a point with the notation "1" instead "13".

Even if I can plot a point with notation "13",
 however the point will be confused with two points whose notations are "1" and "3".

So, to avoid the confusion, I want to specify that the notation "13" is not "1" and "3" (, e.g.,)  by surrounding "13" with a circle. (Or  colored by same red.)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can plot strings using the `text` function. For example:

```
plot(1, 1, xlim=c(0,2), ylim=c(0,2), pch=1, cex=3)  
text(1, 1, "13")
```

[image]

Since `text` is vectorized, you can also do:

```
with(mtcars, plot(hp, wt, type="n"))
with(mtcars, text(hp, wt, round(mpg), col="blue", cex=mpg/20))
```

[image]

Or, with some additional work:

```
library(tidyverse)

col.vec = c("4"="grey40", "6"="green3","8"="darkorange")
cols = recode(mtcars$cyl, !!!col.vec)

with(mtcars, plot(hp, wt, type="n"))
with(mtcars, text(hp, wt, round(mpg), col=cols, cex=mpg/20))
with(mtcars, legend(50,5.2, 
                    bty="n",
                    pch=c(15,15,15),
                    pt.cex=1.5,
                    col=col.vec,
                    title="Cylinders", title.col="grey20",
                    legend=sort(unique(cyl))))
```

[image]

Comment: The third example is great!
Thank you, it's pretty close to what I wanted to do